# Reading data from database and setting data to value in input type in html

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, text, default-value

Hi  I have problem  to be solved.I read data from database setting data to text value in javascript .But the value data does not seen in page correctly.For example if the value is equal to  value="hello friends " only "hello" is seen . How can I solve this problem.

Here is code :-

```
    <input type=" + "text" + " value="+login+" id=" + Type + " name=" + Type + " size=" + "40" + " maxlength=" + "200" + " />

show data:-

    <input type=text value=Lütfen kullanıcı adınızı girin id=Kullanıcı  Girisi name=Kullanıcı  Girisi size=40 maxlength=200 />

only Lütfen is seen..

BlockCode:-

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
               List<LoginVO> loginVO = new List<LoginVO>();
               loginVO = formBUS.Login(GrpID);
               login = loginVO[0].Value;
               sb.AppendLine("<table cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" class=\"custom-tablePopup\">");
               sb.AppendLine("<tr><th>" + Type + ":</th> <th><input type=" + "text" + " value="+login+" id=" + Type + " name=" + Type + " size=" + "40" + " maxlength=" + "200" + " /><th></tr>");

               //SaveData(icerik);
               sb.AppendLine("<tr cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">");
               //sb.AppendLine("<tr><td>" + dr["DrpBanner2"].ToString() + "</td></tr>");
               // icerik = dr["DrpBanner2"].ToString();
               sb.AppendLine("</tr>");
               //icerik = dr["DrpBanner2"].ToString();
               //SaveData(icerik);
               sb.AppendLine("</table>");
               LitformSon.Text += sb.ToString();
```

Comment: what r u trying to do here???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a issue with quotes. Try this;

```
<input type=" + "\"text\"" + " value=\""+login+"\" id=\"" + Type + "\" name=\"" + Type + "\" size=" + "\"40\"" + " maxlength=" + "\"200\"" + " />
```

Thanks!