# get Date from Table (HTML) and set in Input

Tags: angularjs

So I want to get my date that load in HTML table, and when the user click on the row automatically data appears in the HTML input (text).

Someone know how can I make this process? I get my data from my server but I don't set the field when clicked.

Example:

> Html Table:
>
> ----------- ----------- |   Id     | | Name |
>
> ---
>
> ```
>  1        Test
> ```
>
> Input text (Name): Blank
>
> When I click in the row with has ID 1 and Name Test:
>
> Input text (Name): Test

Answer (score 0):

You may  check this link it is usefull for you.
[Reading data from database and setting data to value in input type in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24928895/reading-data-from-database-and-setting-data-to-value-in-input-type-in-html). Method of question is the same as your question.

Comment: Isn't this. I want to do that: Imagine: I have a function that load my data to table ok when init the page (ng-init). So after i load all data when i click in one row in my table, this date rendering in my input (that isn't inside table) automatically.